# Error -- test(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: java, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting error "Unable to discover open pages" when I run the script in Jmeter with more than 50 threads and 250 ramp-up time.
It works fine when no of threads are 40 but, when i increase number of threads let say 50 then, some of the threads throw this error.

```
Versions:
selenium: 3.14
chrome driver: 75.0.3770.8
Google chrome: 75.0.3770.80
JDK: 12.0.1
```

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");

```
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

 //add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 2);

//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// set ExperimentalOption 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();




Error -- test(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RAMBN3R', ip: '192.168.210.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Trace -- org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RAMBN3R', ip: '192.168.210.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
```

Comment: Why it does not recognized chromeDriver version? In the error the version should be shown after `Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver` . try reinstalling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your machine where you're running the tests gets overloaded because 50 instances of Chrome browser [require](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en) 50+ CPU cores and at least 100 GB of RAM.

You can check your operating system resources utilization using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

Actually conducting the load using real browsers is not something which is recommended, if you look into [WebDriver Sampler documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Introduction) you will see:

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So you should be using JMeter's HTTP Request samplers to create the main load and 1-2 real browsers to check client-side performance during the load test.

You can easily simulate thousands of virtual users from a mid-range modern laptop, however if you go for real browser tests you will need 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per virtual user (browser instance) so most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)